# How can I change pushbutton visibility in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

I am trying to create a simple game.

What it should do: Create 2 pushbuttons and when user clicks each button it should disappear.

What it actually does: When I click the first button it disappears. But when I click the 2nd one nothing happens.

```
clear all, clc, close all

fh = figure;

n = 2;
x = ceil(rand(10)*2);
y = ceil(rand(10)*2);

bgh = uibuttongroup('Parent',fh,'Title',...
    'Button Game','Position',[.1 .2 .8 .6]);

for i = 1:n
    rbh1 = uicontrol(bgh,'Style','Pushbutton','String','Red',...
        'Units','normalized','Position',[rand(1) rand(1) x(1,i) y(1,i)]);
    set(rbh1,'CallBack','set(rbh1,''visible'',''off'')')
end

axt = axes('Parent',bgh,'Units','normalized');

axis([0.5 1 0.5 1])
axis square
axis off
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're setting the callback for one handle only. Change the loop bit of your code to the following and it will work.  Since this seems like a learning exercise, I'll leave it to you to explore it and figure out why making this change helps.

```
for i = 1:n
rbh(i) = uicontrol(bgh,'Style','Pushbutton','String','Red',...
'Units','normalized','Position',[rand(1) rand(1) x(1,i) y(1,i)]);

set(rbh(i),'CallBack',['set(rbh( ' num2str(i) '),''visible'',''off'')'])
end
```